# Typedef struct returning different value than stored in C

Tags: c, struct, return, printf, typedef

Maybe I am using a typedef struct completely wrong and am about to ask a stupid question, so please excuse me if that is the case. I have Monster.h.

```
#ifndef MONSTER_H_
#define MONSTER_H_

typedef struct EnemyStats
{
        int EnemyHP;
}EnemyStats;

int Monster(int Selection);
EnemyStats MonsterStats(int Selection);

#endif
```

I then have Monster.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Monster.h"

EnemyStats MonsterStats(int Selection)
{
        EnemyStats value;
        value.EnemyHP = 60;
        return value;
}
```

Now please understand that at the moment I have simplified my code for the purpose of testing this problem, originally I had 3 integers in my typedef struct and was returning value after storing different numbers in each int. Last I have my Test.c file containing the main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Monster.h"

int main()
{
        MonsterStats(1);
        EnemyStats value;
        printf("%d\n", value.EnemyHP);
}
```

On three seperate runs of the program, I get the values:

> 5226069
>
> 12000853
>
> 11939413

I really cannot find anywhere of this occurring and I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong or if I am misusing the struct. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `main` function. The `EnemyStats value` struct never get initialised, so it is just random memory from the stack. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe what you want is:

```
int main()
{   
        EnemyStats value = MonsterStats(1);
        printf("%d\n", value.EnemyHP);
}
```